# Is Gemma Teller afraid of repurcussions?

Tags: sons-of-anarchy

In one of the Sons of Anarchy Season1, Ep < 4, Gemma tells Clay that **Jax is going towards the footsteps of his father and that he needs to set it right - follow the footsteps of the right father**. What does she actually want to do at that point of time? and what is she afraid the most of?

1. That if he does not lead the SOA MC, when they retire they might have repercussions? (Evident from their awareness of Mayans/Niners blow backs and their code of living) (Is it a valid surmise?)
2. It might come to Jax's killing same way she blessed John's death? (She see's parallel's)
3. She is afraid their arrangement Clay - Gemma - Jax  would fall with Jax - Clay fallout. (She tells Tara later "Men need to own their pussy, his has been violated. He will find another. Its what they do!")
4. That she is Afraid at that point of time itself (Jax just found John's book from  the garage) that jax finding about his father's death would lead to Jax killing Gemma and or Clay
5. If club finds out they will kill Gemma AND Clay! (They might be aware that someone other than Clay/Gemma ('Piney/Jury/Irish Father') still living might know of their plot, and they can inform the club with Jax's finding, even if Jax does not act on it)
6. Both Clay and Gemma are afraid of IRA kings and the future of the club.
7. What else?

Does she really have situation analytical ability like Clay?

Comment: These are many half-questions rolled into one. Are you asking what Gemma means? What Gemma fears? What she wants? Whether she has analytical skills? ... these are way too many questions  with way too many implicit assumptions inbetween.